# Arranging roses

Tags: mathematics, geometry, combinatorics

Ten roses are arranged in two rows of five flowers each:

[image]

***What is the minimum number of roses that need to be moved to arrange the flowers into five rows of four roses each?***

*Similar puzzle: [Plant 9 trees in 10 rows of 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29848/plant-9-trees-in-10-rows-of-3)*

Comment: Just to clarify, the rows cannot be collinear like the puzzle you posted in the link?

Comment: Yeah, someone should add that caveat. The original image already contains 10 unique rows of 4 roses each, leaving '0' as the correct answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can solve it by moving only

> 4 roses  (I don't think we can do better)

My drawing :

> [image]
>   [image]
>  in green the original roses, in red the new ones

Comment: I have not been able to find a way to use less than 4. Good going!

Answer (score 0):

## 6.

[image: star]

As you can see, it is a (badly drawn) star, with 5 rows of 4 roses.

Comment: Why would you need to move 10 roses if there are 10? Surely one of them can stay put. And in your drawing 4 of them have actually not moved.