# Orchard planting problem for squares

Tags: mathematics, geometry, combinatorics

The classic [Orchard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchard-planting_problem) [planting](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Orchard-PlantingProblem.html) problem asks for the maximum number of 3-point straight lines attainable from a configuration of $n$ points drawn on a plane.

Here we are interested in a variant of this problem. What is the maximum number of squares attainable  from a configuration of 10 points drawn on a plane? Each corner of an attained square must contain a point.

Here is a similar puzzle for circles: [Orchard planting problem for circles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101719/orchard-planting-problem-for-circles)

Comment: Just to clarify, are all the sides of a square the same length and at a 90 degree angle? Or are trapezium's allowed?

Comment: squares must have sides of the same length and 90 degree angles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May not be optimal but the best I can seem to get is

> $7$ squares

With the following arrangement

> [image]
>  That is, four of side length $1$, one of side length $2$ and two of side length $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Yep that's the solution I found. Not sure if it can be improved.

Comment: I checked that this answer is optimal with a computer program.