# Orchard planting problem of 5 points per circle

Tags: mathematics, geometry

In [General orchard planting problem for circles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101945/general-orchard-planting-problem-for-circles) , the problem of 4 points per circle has been studied.

The problem here is that what is the maximum number of 5-point circles for a configuration of n points drawn on a plane?

It is easy to show that we need 8 points to get two 5-point circles and 9 points to get three 5-point circles
[image]

10 points could reach five 5-point circles:
[image]

11 points to reach seven 5-point circles
and 12 points to reach nine 5-point circles:
[image]

In all pictures above, one point is at infinite point and circle-inversion transformation (turn line into circle) could be used to transform it to normal point.

Comment: What's the red circle in your second picture point to?

Comment: great idea for a problem

Comment: @justhalf Ignore it. It shows that we could not add a third circle to the picture.

Comment: With 12 points you can make 12 5-point circles.  Make a stereographic projection of an icosahedron.  Or project a dodecahedron and you get 24 circles using 20 points.

Comment: astonishing result. Searching by computer and we could not find any combination with 13 5-point circles so that 12 5-point circles are best result of 12 points

Answer (score 1):

Here is the 12 points, 12 5-circles solution I mentioned in a comment.

[image]

And adding a single point in the center gives you 3 more circles.

Answer (score 1):

Add an equivalent result of Florian F. (one infinity point) for 13 points with 15 5-point circles
(where black point and black dash circles are the extra point and 3 extra 5-point circles)
[image]
And similarly we could add one more extra point and 3 extra 5-point circles to reach 14 points with 18 5-point circles and one more point and 2 extra 5-point circles to reach 15 points with 20 5-point circles.